# Netbeans com erro ao iniciar o Tomcat. "Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal Files\Tomcat"

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jdk

Estou com esse problema a dias. Em duas outras maquinas com o mesmo sistema operacional, foi feito o mesmo procedimento de instalação e não ocorreu erro.
Estarei anexando print com o erro. 
Já pesquisei na internet e já tentei varias opções diferentes de solução. Inclusive reinstalar o netbeaans, a JDK e o tomcat(com versão 8.5 e 9.0).Nada funcionou até o momento. 
Alguém que já tenha visto esse problema antes e sabe a solução. Por favor me ajude. 
Informações do sistema:
Windows 7
Netbeans 8.2
Tomcat 9.0 
jdk1.8.0_161
Em outra maquina com os mesmos programas e versões funcionou sem problemas.
"Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal Files\Tomcat"
O erro persiste mesmo colocando um novo projeto werb, no lugar de abrir o projeto já em desenvolvimento. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029810/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-catalina-startup-bootstrap

Comment: Gabriel eu já tentei isso. Eu consigo iniciar o Tomcat individualmente, mas no netbeans que é a IDE que estou querendo usar, da esse erro. E no Eclipse também está com problema. É muito estranho pois em outra maquina o fazendo o mesmo processo funciona sem problemas.